# SSH compatibility issue with Git

Tags: git, ssh, version, incompatibility

After updating Macports today with

```
$ sudo port upgrade
```

Git can't push

```
$ git push
OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 1000005f, you have 1000100f
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

$ ssh -version
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
Bad escape character 'rsion'.

$ uname -a
Darwin foobar.local 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
```

Anyone else?  How to fix this quickly?  (This is stopping me from doing useful work.)

#### Edit: errors I get after rolling back `git-core` and `open-ssl` ports:

```
$ port installed git-core openssh
Warning: port definitions are more than two weeks old, consider using selfupdate
The following ports are currently installed:
  git-core @1.7.5.1_0+doc+python27
  git-core @1.7.5.2_0+doc+python27
  git-core @1.7.7_0+doc+pcre+python27
  git-core @1.7.7.4_0+doc+pcre+python27
  git-core @1.7.9.2_1+credential_osxkeychain+doc+pcre+python27 (active)
  git-core @1.7.9.4_0+credential_osxkeychain+doc+pcre+python27
  openssh @5.8p1_0 (active)
  openssh @5.9p1_0
$ git push
OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 1000004f, you have 1000100f
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to rebuild git too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo port deactivate` the `openssl`, `openssh`, and possibly `git-core` ports, and `sudo port activate` the old versions.  (`port installed openssl git-core openssh` to see these old versions.)  Although I thought this had already been fixed; did you `port selfupdate` first?

Comment: This fixed the issue quickly.  Thanks!  I couldn't do `selfupdate` because the firewall I am behind now forbids `rsync`.

Comment: Actually it still doesn't work.  See the errors I get in the OP.

Comment: I managed to miss the most important one, actually:  you also need to deacrivate/reactivate the old `openssl` port.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Trying updating your openssh (which git is using).

$ sudo port upgrade openssh

I found that at the very end of this thread:
[installing git-core (to upgrade OpenSSL) leads to errors](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.apple.macports.user/27333)